# How do I create a continuous play with items from an array?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this bit of code here and I'm trying to get it to display one item at a time. I want to get it to play the videos one after the other with some input (button or otherwise) in between the videos. Similar to how 5by.com works. It currently shows all my videos in a list. Can anyone help?

`

```
<?php

    $genre = $user_data['interview'];
    $raw_results = mysql_query ("SELECT `link` FROM `short_films` WHERE `genre` LIKE '$genre'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

?>
    <div id="video_player">
        <iframe src="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" type=""></iframe>
    </div>
<?php
    }
    include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

`

Comment: and what is the XML part of it??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to [paginate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination) the results. I'll let you figure that out, but this is the general concept:

```
<video id="video_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" src="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>"></video>

var vid = document.getElementById("video_<?php echo $row['link'] ?>");
vid.onended = function(e) {
      $.ajax({ 
          // get next video and create an element
      });
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how I apply that... sorry.

Comment: Only retrieve one item from the table, and then only show one video at a time. When that video ends, then get the source via an ajax call.

Comment: I need a bit more help on this please. I can't figure out how to make this work and it's due tomorrow...

Comment: hint: use `$_GET['page']` and `LIMIT` in the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

`<script>
        function next_video () {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById ("video_player").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","play.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>`

```
$genre_action       = $user_data['action'];
$genre_adventure    = $user_data['adventure'];
$genre_art          = $user_data['art'];
$genre_animation    = $user_data['animation'];
$genre_documentary  = $user_data['documentary'];
$genre_drama        = $user_data['drama'];
$genre_interview    = $user_data['interview'];
$genre_romance      = $user_data['romance'];
$genre_sf           = $user_data['sf'];
$genre_visual       = $user_data['visual'];
$raw_results = mysql_query ("SELECT `link` FROM `short_films` WHERE `genre` = '$genre_action' OR `genre` = '$genre_adventure' OR `genre` = ' $genre_art' OR `genre` = '$genre_animation' OR `genre` = '$genre_documentary' OR `genre` = '$genre_drama' OR `genre` = '$genre_interview' OR `genre` = '$genre_romance' OR `genre` = '$genre_sf' OR `genre` = '$genre_visual'  LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
?>
<div id="video_player">
    <iframe src="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>" type=""></iframe>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="next_video()">next video</button>
<?php
}
     include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

`

this is what I have so far! i've added the div with the player on another page and then I used include to add it back. my problem is that although the first video plays, I get the 403 error when I click next video (You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.)